# No module named spinup.run

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

Today, I tried to install the spinning up in deep RL from openai. When I copied `python -m spinup.run ppo --env CartPole-v1 --exp_name hello_world` in Anaconda, it showed that

> No module named spinup.run.

Actually, I installed `spinup` package. I did not find the `spinup.run` package.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem so that I can successfully install spinning up in deep RL?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That tripped me up too. I forgot I had to restart the environment ---

Before you open your IDE you need to activate the environment. I'm using Spyder in Anaconda so I open up a terminal and type the following:

```
source activate spinningup
anaconda-navigator &
```

... and then I open up the Spyder editor. Replace Anaconda or Spyder with which ever IDE you are using

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have the packages installed correctly, which you can find in the installation section of the OpenAI SpinningUp website. If you have successfully installed everything, run:

```
python -m spinup.run ppo --exp_name CartPole --env CartPole-v0
```